# How to update a session variable after request is processed

Tags: asp.net, session-state

I have an object that I need to store in the session.

At the beginning of each request, I copy the object to the HttpContext.Current.Items collection so it can be reused during the request.

During the request, the state of the object can be modified, so I need to write it back out to the session so that it can be used for the next request.

I tried updating it via the HttpApplication.EndRequest event handler, but I discovered that the HttpContext.Current.Session is null by this point.

Is there another event handler in HttpApplication that occurs after a request has been processed, but within which I can still access the HttpContext.Current.Session?

Comment: Once again - WHY are you copying a session variable to HttpContext.Current.Items?? Doesn't make sense.

Comment: Why are you copying out the session objects? Why aren't you just updating the session object in question directly?

Comment: Sometimes our app is set up with <sessionState mode="SQLServer"> for load balancing.  My understanding is that updating session objects in this mode reads and writes to the SQL server, so caching the object during the request avoids this.

Comment: I cannot make any comment on exactly how the SQL Server based session information works, but I would *guess* the simple ability to update the session directly (and not via the strange process you're trying) is worth it over the overhead of SQL Server access. I'm happy to be proved wrong

Answer (score 0):

The session is available from the **HttpApplication.PostRequestHandlerExecute** event, which according to the documentation:

*"Occurs when the ASP.NET event handler (for example, a page or an XML Web service) finishes execution."*

This page was helpful in understanding the sequence of HttpApplication events:

http://blog.dotnetclr.com/archive/2007/03/14/HttpApplication-pipeline-demystified.aspx